# Get Files From Sdcard

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to get all .mp3 files from sdcard, even from the subfolders.. Here is the code I use..

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<File> songs = walkdir(home);
}

    public ArrayList<File> walkdir(File dir) {
    String pattern = ".mp3";
    File listFiles[] = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<File> songs = new ArrayList<File>();
    response.setText("listFiles : " + listFiles.length);

    if(listFiles != null) {
        for(File file : listFiles) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(file);
            } else {
                /////// Toast \\\\\\\\\\\\
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File : " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(file.getName().endsWith(pattern)) {
                    songs.add(file);
                    ////// This doesn't happen...
                    response.setText("Found Song : " + file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return songs;
}
```

The weird thing that listFiles.length returns 10 and when I Toast files under the comment "Toast", I get more than 50 Toast, also.. I have a folder that contains more than 40 songs Arabic-English.. In

In the Toast, I get the names of arabic songs.. but I don't get the English ones..

Thanks :)

Comment: Note that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is for [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is not usually an "sdcard". You may have better luck using the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider` to find your MP3 streams.

Comment: I can't think of a worse way to debug than `Toast`.  Why don't you step through your code with the debugger and see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

`File home`. You are not using `home`. `walkdir(musicPath);`. What is musicPath? `ArrayList<File> songs = new ArrayList<File>();`. walkdir() is a recursive function so you are creating a new `song` for every recursion. Put that line outside walkdir(). `.contains(pattern)`. Change to `.endsWith(pattern)`.

Comment: My fault.. I just added a wrong code.. I also tried both endsWith and contains and both don't work..

Comment: What does not work? Did you put that line out? Please comment!

Comment: `ArrayList<File> songs = new ArrayList<File>();`. You did not take that line out. You have to! Then edit your code here.

Comment: `response.setText()`. You have a lot of such statements. Butyou will only see the last ececuted one. Yoy should use an `add()` or `append()` instead to see all. And inspect `song.size()` in onCreate when done.